# Remix js throws 403 error while making POST request in production environment, but working fine in local environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, remix.run

I have this remix.js project while making POST request in production environment it throws 403 forbidden error but working fine in local environment

[this is the request payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd55s.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOOw7.png)

here is the error and payload and headers that i am passing in request
[error code and request payload that i am sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc6hk.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A 403 error means that whatever/whoever is making this call does not have permission to access it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

You may need to whitelist an IP address or client credentials for the production environment or perhaps referrer sent in the headers is invalid. Or it could be that you are missing an environment variable in your production environment, causing the url or other request details to be missing.

If you can provide the code, you should be able to get better help. But here's some ideas:

https://www.plesk.com/blog/various/403-forbidden-error-what-is-it-how-to-fix-it/